# How to multiply each digit in a number efficiently

Tags: math, language-agnostic

I want to multiply every digit in a number to each other.

For example

```
515 would become 25(i.e 5*1*5)
10 would become 0(i.e 1*0)
111111 would become 1(i.e 1*1*1*1*1*1)
```

I used this code to do it

```
public static int evalulate(int no)
{
    if(no==0)return 0;
    int temp=1;

    do
    {
        temp=(no%10)*temp;
        no=no/10;
    }while(no>0);

    return temp;
}
```

problem is I want to evaluate for about a **billion** numbers like this

```
for(int i=0;i<1000000000;i++)evaluate(i);
```

This takes about **146** seconds on my processor.I want to evaluate it within **some** seconds.

So,is it possible to optimize this code using some `shift`,`and`,`or` operators so that I can reduce the time to evaluate **without using multiple threads or parallelizing it**

Thanks

Comment: *This takes about 146 seconds on my processor* on which language, compiler version, OS, machine specifications? By the way, .net **is not a programming language**.

Comment: Conquer the space of target numbers systematically. E.g. once you did `12`, computing `121`, `122`, `123` etc. each requires only one additional operation.

Comment: 146 is technically "some" seconds.. Have you considered parallelizing?

Comment: @KarthikT how would you parallelize this?

Comment: @KeithNicholas yes am comfortable with any of them..i guess the only way to optimize the code would be using some bit level operators which are available in all languages

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Easy, the result of evaluate(i) is not dependent on anything but i, so you can do the calls separately parallelized.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Havent given too much thought.. but cant you run it in 4 threads, each with a quarter of the numbers? Still at best i guess only 4 x improvement..

Comment: no, @jogojapan suggestion is likely fastest.  with possibly abort on zero

Comment: This looks like a problem from Project Euler or another programming contest site. What's the motivation for this?

Comment: 1) You can abort the calculation early if you multiply by zero, as it will never become non zero after that. 2) You can skip over large ranges of numbers that are guaranteed to have a zero in them, e.g. skip from 900,000,000 to 911,111,111 saving 11,111,111 calls!

Comment: Are the inputs sequential? Because evaluate(1235) is trivial after you evaluate(1234). You just take the last interim result evaluate(123)*5. Obviously, that recurses to evaluate(12)*3 etc. And as Patashu suggested, you can truncate the iteration early if you have a zero interim result.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587532/how-to-calculate-the-digit-products-of-the-consecutive-numbers-efficiently

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, figure out how many numbers you can store in memory. For this example, let's say you can store 999 numbers.

Your first step will be to pre-calculate the products of digits for all numbers from 0-999, and store that in memory. So, you'd have an array along the lines of:

```
  multLookup = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
                0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
                0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18,
                0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27,
                0, 4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36,
                ...]
```

Now, you'd break your number up into a bunch of 3 digit numbers. For example, if your number is `1739203423`, you'd break it up into `1`, `739`, `203`, and `423`. You'd look each of these up in your `multLookup` array, and multiply the results together, like so:

```
  solution = multLookup[1] * multLookup[739] * multLookup[203] * multLookup[423];
```

With this approach, you will have sped up your calculations by a factor of 3 (since we picked 999 items to store in memory). To speed it up by 5, store 99999 numbers in memory and follow the same steps. In your case, speeding it up by 5 means you'll arrive at your solution in **29.2 seconds**.

Note: the gain isn't exactly linear with respect to how many numbers you store in memory. See jogojapan's reasoning in the comments under this answer for why that is.

If you know more about the order in which your numbers show up, or the range of your numbers (say your input is only in the range of [0, 10000]), you can make this algorithm smarter.

In your example, you're using a for loop to iterate from 0 to 1000000000. In this case, this approach will be super efficient because the memory won't page-fault very frequently and there will be fewer cache-misses.

***But wait!*** You can make this even faster (for your specific for-loop iteration example)!! How, you ask? Caching! Lets say you're going through 10 digit numbers.

Let's say you start off at `8934236000`. Based on the 999 digits in memory solution, you'd break this down into `8`, `934`, `236`, and `000`. Then you'd multiply:

```
solution = multLookup[8] * multLookup[934] * multLookup[236] * multLookup[0];
```

Next, you'd take `8934236001`, break it down to `8`, `934`, `236`, and `001`, and multiply:

```
solution = multLookup[8] * multLookup[934] * multLookup[236] * multLookup[1];
```

And so on... But we notice that the first three lookups are the same for the next 997 iterations! So, we cache that.

```
cache = multLookup[8] * multLookup[934] * multLookup[236];
```

And then we use the cache as such:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    solution = cache * i;
}
```

And just like that, we've almost reduced the time by a factor of 4. So you take the ~29.2 second solution you had, and divide that by 4 to go through all billion numbers in **~7.3 seconds**

Comment: I like the approach, but for the time estimates you need to take into account that fetching pre-calculated results from memory (through array lookup) also takes time. The more you store, the longer it will take (as it increasingly won't fit into cache).

Comment: Fair enough, I should've been more clear about this instead of alluding to a linear gain.

Answer (score 6):

*If* you can store the result of each operation for all your numbers.. Then you can use [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). That way you need to only calculate 1 digit.

```
int prodOf(int num){
   // can be optimized to store 1/10 of the numbers, since the last digit will always be processed
   static std::vector<int> memo(<max number of iterations>, -1); 
   if(num == 0) return 0;

   if(memo[num] != -1 )return memo[num];

   int prod = (num%10)  * prodOf(num/10);

   memo[num] = prod;

   return prod;
}
```

Comment: You'd need to be careful with a memoization approach, an array with hundreds of millions of elements might cause OutOfMemoryException

Comment: @Patashu I once had a million items array in a C application and never lacked of memory.

Comment: @Patashu ya, never tried it in this scale. Hence my disclaimer.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza A billion is a thousand times larger than a million :)

Comment: @Patashu still you won't add the solution of multiplying all the elements, otherwise it would be faster not storing any result at all to begin with.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yeah, I can see storing only the result of the first million calculations, for example

Comment: +1 for a generally useful idea. (One important question here will be whether fetching memoized data from memory will really be faster than recalculating it, or, to put it differently, how much of the memoized data will fit into L1 cache.)

Comment: @jogojapan There is reasonable locality (good even.. tho i do not have the experience to judge).. that should help.. but even worst case.. is it actually likely for a iterative operation to be faster than ram based lookup?

Comment: Made tests using OP's code and yours in Java 64-bit JVM with 5 GBs of memory. OP's code took approximately 31 secs and yours between 2 and 6 secs, but never tested if your method returned the right values.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks for testing, 15 x improvement is more than I had expected.

Comment: Yes but with a downside of huge memory usage: 5GB!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza whoa.. that can be reduced to 500 mb i guess if we only store the numbers upto (max - 1) digits

Answer (score 1):

Some test i made,
With simple C/C++ code on my PC (Xeon 3.2GHz),

> last no = i = 999999999 ==> 387420489 nb sec 23

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

#undef _TRACE_

inline int evaluate(int no)
{
#ifdef _TRACE_
    std::cout << no;
#endif

    if(no==0)return 0;
    int temp=1;

    do
    {
        temp=(no%10)*temp;
        no=no/10;
    }while(no>0);
#ifdef _TRACE_
    std::cout << " => " <<  temp << std::endl;
#endif // _TRACE_
    return temp;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    int last = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for(/*int i = 0*/;i<1000000000;++i) {
        last = evaluate(i);
    }
    std::cout << "last no = i = " << (i-1) << " ==> " << last << std::endl;
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> end(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    std::cout << "nb sec " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end - start).count() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I also tested the loop split over multiple thread with openMP and result is 0 second,
So I would say that it would be useful if you consider performance problem of using a real efficient language.

```
pragma omp parallel for 
for(int i = 0;i<1000000000;++i) {
     /*last[threadID][i] = */evaluate(i);
}
```

Comment: Just tried recursion. Seems like it's slower by the slightest little bit, but basically the same speed.

Comment: I'm sorry i didn't see the "public" keyword in front of the static function! So it's not C, but more something like C#... So forget OpenMP...

Comment: The question originally specified for the four languages.

Comment: Ho yes, I'm still beginner here :), you are right the tag used by the question are clear.