# How to calculate the digit products of the consecutive numbers efficiently?

Tags: c#, math, language-agnostic

I'm trying to calculate the product of digits of each number of a sequence of numbers, for example:

> 21, 22, 23 ... 98, 99 ..

would be:

> 2, 4, 6 ... 72, 81 ..

To reduce the complexity, I would consider only the [[consecutive numbers](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consecutive_integer)] in a limited length of digits, such as from `001` to `999` or from `0001` to `9999`.

However, when the sequence is large, for example, `1000000000`, repeatedly *extract the digits and then multiply* for every number would be inefficient.

The basic idea is to skip the consecutive zeros we will encounter during the calculation, something like:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;

// note the digit product is not given with the iteration
// we would need to provide a delegate for the calculation
public static partial class NumericExtensions {
    public static void NumberIteration(
            this int value, Action<int, int[]> delg, int radix=10) {
        var digits=DigitIterator(value, radix).ToArray();
        var last=digits.Length-1;
        var emptyArray=new int[] { };
        var pow=(Func<int, int, int>)((x, y) => (int)Math.Pow(x, 1+y));
        var weights=Enumerable.Repeat(radix, last-1).Select(pow).ToArray();

        for(int complement=radix-1, i=value, j=i; i>0; i-=1)
            if(i>j)
                delg(i, emptyArray);
            else if(0==digits[0]) {
                delg(i, emptyArray);

                var k=0;

                for(; k<last&&0==digits[k]; k+=1)
                    ;

                var y=(digits[k]-=1);

                if(last==k||0!=y) {
                    if(0==y) { // implied last==k
                        digits=new int[last];
                        last-=1;
                    }

                    for(; k-->0; digits[k]=complement)
                        ;
                }
                else {
                    j=i-weights[k-1];
                }
            }
            else {
                // receives digits of a number which doesn't contain zeros 
                delg(i, digits);

                digits[0]-=1;
            }

        delg(0, emptyArray);
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> DigitIterator(int value, int radix) {
        if(-2<radix&&radix<2)
            radix=radix<0?-2:2;

        for(int remainder; 0!=value; ) {
            value=Math.DivRem(value, radix, out remainder);
            yield return remainder;
        }
    }
}
```

This is only for the enumeration of numbers, to avoid numbers which contain zeros to be calculated in the first place, the digit products are not yet given by the code; but generate the digit products by providing a delegate to perform the calculation will still take time.

How to calculate the digit products of the consecutive numbers efficiently?

Comment: Dear down-voters/close-voters, if you voted for the reason that I didn't show my research effort, I've revised; if it's the reason that the question is not considered practical to you, my personal perspective is that sometimes for the cryptographic related problems would use various mathematical approaches for the analysis of numeric characteristic, I'd think that a simple and effecient way make things easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: The "start from anywhere, extended range" version...

This version has a signficantly extended range, and therefore returns an `IEnumerable<long>` instead of an `IEnumerable<int>` - multiply enough digits together and you exceed `int.MaxValue`. It also goes up to 10,000,000,000,000,000 - not quite the full range of `long`, but pretty big :) You can start anywhere you like, and it will carry on from there to its end.

```
class DigitProducts
{
    private static readonly int[] Prefilled = CreateFirst10000();

    private static int[] CreateFirst10000()
    {
        // Inefficient but simple, and only executed once.
        int[] values = new int[10000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            int product = 1;
            foreach (var digit in i.ToString())
            {
                product *= digit -'0';
            }
            values[i] = product;
        }
        return values;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<long> GetProducts(long startingPoint)
    {
        if (startingPoint >= 10000000000000000L || startingPoint < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        int a = (int) (startingPoint / 1000000000000L);
        int b = (int) ((startingPoint % 1000000000000L) / 100000000);
        int c = (int) ((startingPoint % 100000000) / 10000);
        int d = (int) (startingPoint % 10000);

        for (; a < 10000; a++)
        {
            long aMultiplier = a == 0 ? 1 : Prefilled[a];
            for (; b < 10000; b++)
            {
                long bMultiplier = a == 0 && b == 0 ? 1
                                 : a != 0 && b < 1000 ? 0
                                 : Prefilled[b];
                for (; c < 10000; c++)
                {
                    long cMultiplier = a == 0 && b == 0 && c == 0 ? 1
                                     : (a != 0 || b != 0) && c < 1000 ? 0
                                     : Prefilled[c];

                    long abcMultiplier = aMultiplier * bMultiplier * cMultiplier;
                    for (; d < 10000; d++)
                    {
                        long dMultiplier = 
                            (a != 0 || b != 0 || c != 0) && d < 1000 ? 0
                            : Prefilled[d];
                        yield return abcMultiplier * dMultiplier;
                    }
                    d = 0;
                }
                c = 0;
            }
            b = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: Performance analysis

I haven't looked at the performance in *detail*, but I believe at this point the bulk of the work is just simply iterating over a billion values. A simple `for` loop which just returns the value itself takes over 5 seconds on my laptop, and iterating over the digit products only takes a bit over 6 seconds, so I don't think there's much more room for optimization - if you want to go from the start. If you want to (efficiently) start from a different position, more tweaks are required.

---

Okay, here's an attempt which uses an iterator block to yield the results, and precomputes the first thousand results to make things a bit quicker.

I've tested it up to about 150 million, and it's correct so far. It only goes returns the first billion results - if you needed more than that, you could add another block at the end...

```
static IEnumerable<int> GetProductDigitsFast()
{
    // First generate the first 1000 values to cache them.
    int[] productPerThousand = new int[1000];

    // Up to 9
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        productPerThousand[x] = x;
        yield return x;
    }
    // Up to 99
    for (int y = 1; y < 10; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            productPerThousand[y * 10 + x] = x * y;
            yield return x * y;
        }
    }
    // Up to 999
    for (int x = 1; x < 10; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++)
            {
                int result = x * y * z;
                productPerThousand[x * 100 + y * 10 + z] = x * y * z;
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }

    // Now use the cached values for the rest
    for (int x = 0; x < 1000; x++)
    {
        int xMultiplier = x == 0 ? 1 : productPerThousand[x];
        for (int y = 0; y < 1000; y++)
        {
            // We've already yielded the first thousand
            if (x == 0 && y == 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            // If x is non-zero and y is less than 100, we've
            // definitely got a 0, so the result is 0. Otherwise,
            // we just use the productPerThousand.
            int yMultiplier = x == 0 || y >= 100 ? productPerThousand[y]
                                                 : 0;
            int xy = xMultiplier * yMultiplier;
            for (int z = 0; z < 1000; z++)
            {
                if (z < 100)
                {
                    yield return 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return xy * productPerThousand[z];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tested this by comparing it with the results of an incredibly naive version:

```
static IEnumerable<int> GetProductDigitsSlow()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
    {
        int product = 1;
        foreach (var digit in i.ToString())
        {
            product *= digit -'0';
        }
        yield return product;
    }
}
```

Hope this idea is of some use... I don't know how it compares to the others shown here in terms of performance.

EDIT: Expanding this slightly, to use simple loops where we know the results will be 0, we end up with fewer conditions to worry about, but for some reason it's actually slightly slower. (This really surprised me.) This code is longer, but possibly a little easier to follow.

```
static IEnumerable<int> GetProductDigitsFast()
{
    // First generate the first 1000 values to cache them.
    int[] productPerThousand = new int[1000];

    // Up to 9
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        productPerThousand[x] = x;
        yield return x;
    }
    // Up to 99
    for (int y = 1; y < 10; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            productPerThousand[y * 10 + x] = x * y;
            yield return x * y;
        }
    }
    // Up to 999
    for (int x = 1; x < 10; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++)
            {
                int result = x * y * z;
                productPerThousand[x * 100 + y * 10 + z] = x * y * z;
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }

    // Use the cached values up to 999,999
    for (int x = 1; x < 1000; x++)
    {
        int xMultiplier = productPerThousand[x];
        for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
        {
            yield return 0;
        }
        for (int y = 100; y < 1000; y++)
        {
            yield return xMultiplier * y;
        }
    }

    // Now use the cached values for the rest
    for (int x = 1; x < 1000; x++)
    {
        int xMultiplier = productPerThousand[x];
        // Within each billion, the first 100,000 values will all have
        // a second digit of 0, so we can just yield 0.
        for (int y = 0; y < 100 * 1000; y++)
        {
            yield return 0;
        }
        for (int y = 100; y < 1000; y++)
        {
            int yMultiplier = productPerThousand[y];
            int xy = xMultiplier * yMultiplier;
            // Within each thousand, the first 100 values will all have
            // an anti-penulimate digit of 0, so we can just yield 0.
            for (int z = 0; z < 100; z++)
            {
                yield return 0;
            }
            for (int z = 100; z < 1000; z++)
            {
                yield return xy * productPerThousand[z];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is easier to understand than some of the others. I think the iterator block is relatively slow, but use array(s) as the cache is a good idea. The insteresting thing is how the cache is used, for example, for a 10 digits number `1234567891`, we can seperate it to `1,234,567,891` or `1,23,456,789,1`. When the numbers are more larger, there are various strategies of the seperation of digits and the cache size. I've once thought that bisection the length of digits would be a good way for divide and conquer, but I don't know whether it's the fact.

Comment: @KenKin: I don't think the iterator block makes much difference. I've just written an alternative version which accepts an `Action<int>`, and both versions take about 6 seconds on my laptop to work through all 1 billion that it produces.

Comment: You are right, no much difference. Perhaps the subtle difference occured in my test was caused by the instruction-generation or optimization. But the efficiency between the iterator pattern and tail recursion is tricky.

Comment: By the way, the code is the best formatted and most readable of all the answers ..

Comment: @KenKin: Thanks - I've certainly found it simplish to understand, but confess to not understanding some of the others. I'm working on a way of making it simpler but longer (and hopefully faster) now...

Comment: @KenKin: Out of interest, how does my solution stack up performance-wise with the others? It seems to be faster than Ben's second approach, but I haven't tested all the rest. Mine is tricky to "start from the middle" without the cost of iterating over all the previous values, but it would definitely be feasible with a bit of work. (Under 1000 it's probably not worth bothering; over 1000 you can just do the work for the first 1000 without yielding, then work out the appropriate initial values of x, y and z.)

Comment: @KenKin: I've added a note about performance at the start of the answer.

Comment: Thank you! For all the answers so far here, the fastest approach for calculation of a whole range from 0 to maximum value is Ben's. It's true that the second approach of Ben's for start from the middle is slightly slower. To be honest, for a implementation using iterator pattern, your answer is much more effective than what I've ever tried.

Comment: @KenKin: Ben's second, or first? Because the first one is effectively a non-starter for a huge number, and the second one is much slower on my machine. I still have another thing to try though...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you asked `Ben's second, or first?` .. do you mean the fastest one? If yes, I mean the first of Ben's, but do you consider which is a non-starter approach? Is it because the maximum number is limited to an int?

Comment: @KenKin: It's more than "just limited to an int" - it doesn't handle 999999999, as you yourself commented (at least not without special flags to enable huge arrays)... which given the question, was a requirement, I'd have thought, given that the question talks about "However, when the sequence is large, for example, 1000000000..."

Comment: Hmm .. the question didn't put the limitation on the implementation detail, but similarly, an answer which is conceptually efficient is also correct. It seems I trapped myself by asking a question which can actually have various correct answer. Okay, it's my bad, and I'd better award the bounty and mark the accepted answer carefully. I'm interested in *another thing to try* you told.

Comment: @KenKin: Yes, that idea didn't pan out in the end, I'm afraid :( You also need to be clear about what kind of efficiency you're interested in - clearly Ben's isn't *memory* efficient. But I'm not interested in the bounty... I want to understand your requirements better.

Comment: The idea of how to use the characteristic of numbers is important,and so is the feasibility. An solution which can already deal with any big number is better than a solution is extensible for a bigger number. There several cases I considered *not* feasible,for exmaple,simply make a lookup table for all the numbers and products which possibly considered the fastest. I guess it would be an algorithm which has a balance between the time complexity and the space complexity,and the best is if both are the minimum than other approaches. But..I'm not sure whether I should make such the requirements.

Comment: @KenKin: How will you actually *use* the result? Would you typically be starting at a large number and then continue to another large number? Any idea how long you'll need the sequence to be? Maybe I should generalize my code to take a starting number, and make it work for any `long`. (I assume you don't need more than that?)

Comment: Sorry, I believe that I was missing your point and my earlier replying seems to be irrelevant and has been deleted. Here we go:

Comment: `Would you typically be starting at a large number and then continue to another large number?`In most of the cases, yes, but the actual range is undefined. `Any idea how long you'll need the sequence to be?` What I thought of is as from 0 to the maximum number of given length of digits, since a range other than that is smaller. `Maybe I should generalize my code to take a starting number, and make it work for any long.` Taking a starting number is just good whether it's for `int` or `long`.

Comment: @KenKin: Thanks. One more check - would you be okay with it using a "cache" of 10K instead of 1K values? It'll make the eventual code simpler :) (I may not get round to writing the code until about 12 hours from now, I'm afraid - but I'll do it when I can.)

Comment: It's fine with me. Since you're not interested in the bounty, I'm going to award it to Ben, and accept your answer. Thank you so much for your time/effort on this and the good answer.

Comment: I worried about what I said might be misleading that *I'm not expecting an updating*. It's fine with me for the *one more check*. I do expect the updating when you have time, pardon my querying ..

Comment: @KenKin: Sorry, I'll get round to it in a bit - but I'm currently on a work offsite, so it may well not be until the weekend.

Comment: Oh, don't be sorry, just take your time. Whenever it is convenient to you to update would be fine. I just worried about the my poor expression with the words to be misunderstood. BTW, work off site is tiring, wish you well.

Comment: @KenKin: Have a look now - the new code is at the start of the answer. It's pretty similar to the previous version in terms of general idea, so it shouldn't be too hard to follow.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are earlier than you told. I've tested the code, somehow the previous one is twice as fast as the updated. I've once guess it's because of I tested it on a 32 bits machine, I then change `long` to `int`, and still the case. For making the test simpler, I iterated the products in a foreach loop from `0` and used a local variable to control the iteration like this way `foreach(var x in GetProducts(0))
 if(--i==0)
  break;
`. Note that I'm not requesting for another update, the efficiency have been high enough of its purpose, just wondering. Any idea?

Comment: @KenKin: I really don't know, I'm afraid. Maybe the processor cache isn't big enough to hold the array in uber-fast memory?

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in a dp-like fashion with the following recursive formula:

```
n                   n <= 9
a[n/10] * (n % 10)  n >= 10
```

where `a[n]` is the result of the multiplication of the digits of `n`.

This leads to a simple `O(n)` algorithm: When calculating `f(n)` assuming you have already calculated `f(·)` for smaller `n`, you can just use the result from all digits but the last multiplied with the last digit.

```
a = range(10)
for i in range(10, 100):
    a.append(a[i / 10] * (i % 10))
```

You can get rid of the expensive multiplication by just adding doing `a[n - 1] + a[n / 10]` for numbers where the last digit isn't `0`.

Comment: Thank you for answering. BTW, multiplication seems not as expensive as division though.

Comment: @KenKin Is this what you were looking for? I had glossed over your code but you didn't seem to have that already.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, but you can easily get rid of that as well. I thought it would make the code unnecessarily complex, since it doesn't change the basic idea that is used.

Comment: Oh, the code I proposed **does** solve the question, and not solving #8 directly. Personally, I don't think it is complex, but it's true that we are sharing the same idea, and I so upvoted your answer.

Comment: @KenKin I didn't mean to suggest your code doesn't work or anything. As for being more complex, have a look at Ben's answer. It's also based on the same exact same idea, but it's more optimized. That's what I meant by more complex ;) You could go ahead and replace his `prior * j` with a repeated addition which should make it even faster, but that'll make it even more unreadable.

Comment: The code looks fine(Ben's), but by my personal understanding, tail call of recursion should be conceptually as same efficient as the non-recursive implementation ..

Comment: @KenKin: It might, since it's inside a loop you only need one addition per loop.  The `sweep*10 + j` can also be replaced with a simple increment.  But yes, that hurts readability.

Answer (score 4):

The key to efficiency is not to enumerate the numbers and extract the digits, but to enumerate digits and generate the numbers.

```
int[] GenerateDigitProducts( int max )
{
    int sweep = 1;
    var results = new int[max+1];
    for( int i = 1; i <= 9; ++i ) results[i] = i;
    // loop invariant: all values up to sweep * 10 are filled in
    while (true) {
        int prior = results[sweep];
        if (prior > 0) {
            for( int j = 1; j <= 9; ++j ) {
                int k = sweep * 10 + j; // <-- the key, generating number from digits is much faster than decomposing number into digits
                if (k > max) return results;
                results[k] = prior * j;
                // loop invariant: all values up to k are filled in
            }
        }
        ++sweep;
    }
}
```

It's up to the caller to ignore the results which are less than `min`.

- Demo: http://ideone.com/rMK7Sh

---

Here's a low space version using the branch-bound-prune technique:

```
static void VisitDigitProductsImpl(int min, int max, System.Action<int, int> visitor, int build_n, int build_ndp)
{
    if (build_n >= min && build_n <= max) visitor(build_n, build_ndp);

    // bound
    int build_n_min = build_n;
    int build_n_max = build_n;

    do {
        build_n_min *= 10;
        build_n_max *= 10;
        build_n_max +=  9;

        // prune
        if (build_n_min > max) return;
    } while (build_n_max < min);

    int next_n = build_n * 10;
    int next_ndp = 0;
    // branch
    // if you need to visit zeros as well: VisitDigitProductsImpl(min, max, visitor, next_n, next_ndp);
    for( int i = 1; i <= 9; ++i ) {
        next_n++;
        next_ndp += build_ndp;
        VisitDigitProductsImpl(min, max, visitor, next_n, next_ndp);
    }

}

static void VisitDigitProducts(int min, int max, System.Action<int, int> visitor)
{
    for( int i = 1; i <= 9; ++i )
        VisitDigitProductsImpl(min, max, visitor, i, i);
}
```

- Demo: http://ideone.com/AIal1L

Comment: @KenKin: That's generating number from digits and induction.  `sweep` contains the concatenation of the leftmost digits, `j` is the next digit, `k` is the concatenation.  This uses the recursive formula mentioned by phantom, but it builds the numbers up one digit at a time instead of pulling digits off.

Comment: Well, seems that I didn't read it carefully enough. Thank you very much.

Comment: I've tested the code. I think it's a very efficient solution, the only problem I've encountered is when I tried to use `999999999` as `max`, I got an `OutOfMemoryException`. Is there a chance to make it an implementation without allocating a big `int` array?

Comment: @KenKin: Well, the array isn't just an implementation detail, it's how I returned the results.  This could be done using a lot less space using a recursive definition, if you're ok with the `(n, digitProduct[n])` tuples being generated in a weird order (for example, if you need a fairly small slice out of a large `n`, then the results could conditionally be stored into a small array -- but then I'd want to add some branch, bound, and prune logic as well).

Comment: @KenKin: Do you have a particular example in mind, where the results would fit in memory but the whole array starting at `0` won't?

Comment: By the description of this question, no, there's not a case should be. But I'm curious if that can be done by making some change with your code, since in my testing, it's faster than my implementation. Or, if there's a way that it can started from a number other than `0`, for example, from `123456781` to `999999999`, but which is not defined by the question. However, I'm afraid that to ask a furthur question for this attempt would be uncomfortable to the community ..

Comment: It's a pity that I cannot make a version of code without the storage from this implementation, but I think this is the most promising answer for the bounty till now.

Comment: @KenKin: Added the streaming version which only requires `O(log(max))` space.  It's probably just a little slower than the other.

Answer (score 2):

I end up with very simple code as the following:

- Code:

  ```
  public delegate void R(
      R delg, int pow, int rdx=10, int prod=1, int msd=0);

  R digitProd=
      default(R)!=(digitProd=default(R))?default(R):
      (delg, pow, rdx, prod, msd) => {
          var x=pow>0?rdx:1;

          for(var call=(pow>1?digitProd:delg); x-->0; )
              if(msd>0)
                  call(delg, pow-1, rdx, prod*x, msd);
              else
                  call(delg, pow-1, rdx, x, x);
      };
  ```

  `msd` is the *most significant digit*, it's like [most significant bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit) in binary.

The reason I didn't choose to use iterator pattern is it takes more time than the method call. The complete code(with test) is put at the rear of this answer.

Note that the line `default(R)!=(digitProd=default(R))?default(R): ...` is only for assigment of `digitProd`, since the delegate cannot be used before it is assigned. We can actually write it as:

- Alternative syntax:

  ```
  var digitProd=default(R);

  digitProd=
      (delg, pow, rdx, prod, msd) => {
          var x=pow>0?rdx:1;

          for(var call=(pow>1?digitProd:delg); x-->0; )
              if(msd>0)
                  call(delg, pow-1, rdx, prod*x, msd);
              else
                  call(delg, pow-1, rdx, x, x);
      };
  ```

The disadvantage of this implementation is that it cannot started from a particular number but the maximum number of full digits.

There're some simple ideas that I solve it:

1. **Recursion**

   The delegate(`Action`) `R` is a recursive delegate definition which is used as [tail call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) recursion, for both the algorithm and the delegate which receives the result of digit product.

   And the other ideas below explain for why recursion.
2. **No division**

   For consecutive numbers, use of the division to extract each digit is considered low efficiency, thus I chose to operate on the digits directly with recursion in a down-count way.

   For example, with 3 digits of the number `123`, it's one of the 3 digits numbers started from `999`:

   > 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 [1] 0 -- the first level of recursion
   >
   > 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 [2] 1 0 -- the second level of recursion
   >
   > 9 8 7 6 5 4 [3] 2 1 0 -- the third level of recursion
3. **Don't cache**

   As we can see that this answer

   [How to multiply each digit in a number efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17357368/how-to-multiply-each-digit-in-a-number-efficiently/17357707#17357707)

   suggested to use the mechanism of caching, but for the consecutive numbers, we don't, since it **is** the cache.

   For the numbers `123, 132, 213, 231, 312, 321`, the digit products are identical. Thus for a cache, we can reduce the items to store which are only the same digits with different order(permutations), and we can regard them as the same key.

   However, sorting the digits also takes time. With a `HashSet` implemented collection of keys, we pay more storage with more items; even we've reduced the items, we still spend time on equality comparing. There does not seem to be a hash function better than **use its value for equality comparing**, and which is just the result we are calculating. For example, excepting 0 and 1, there're only 36 combinations in the multiplication table of two digits.

   Thus, as long as the calculation is efficient enough, we can consider the algorithm itself is a **virtual cache** without costing a storage.
4. **Reduce the time on calculation of numbers contain zero(s)**

   For the digit products of consecutive numbers, we will encounter:

   > 1 zero per 10
   >
   > 10 consecutive zeros per 100
   >
   > 100 consecutive zeros per 1000

   and so on. Note that there are still 9 zeros we will encounter with `per 10` in `per 100`. The count of zeros can be calculated with the following code:

   ```
   static int CountOfZeros(int n, int r=10) {
       var powerSeries=n>0?1:0;

       for(var i=0; n-->0; ++i) {
           var geometricSeries=(1-Pow(r, 1+n))/(1-r);
           powerSeries+=geometricSeries*Pow(r-1, 1+i);
       }

       return powerSeries;
   }
   ```

   For `n` is the count of digits, `r` is the radix. The number would be a [power series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series) which calculated from a [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series) and plus 1 for the `0`.

   For example, the numbers of 4 digits, the zeros we will encounter are:

   > (1)+(((1*9)+11)*9+111)*9 = (1)+(1*9*9*9)+(11*9*9)+(111*9) = 2620

   For this implementation, we do **not** really skip the calculation of numbers contain zero. The reason is the result of a shallow level of recursion is reused with the recursive implementation which are what we can regard as *cached*. The attempting of multiplication with a single zero can be detected and avoided before it performs, and we can pass a zero to the next level of recursion directly. However, just multiply will not cause much of performance impact.

---

The complete code:

```
public static partial class TestClass {
    public delegate void R(
        R delg, int pow, int rdx=10, int prod=1, int msd=0);

    public static void TestMethod() {
        var power=9;
        var radix=10;
        var total=Pow(radix, power);

        var value=total;
        var count=0;

        R doNothing=
            (delg, pow, rdx, prod, msd) => {
            };

        R countOnly=
            (delg, pow, rdx, prod, msd) => {
                if(prod>0)
                    count+=1;
            };

        R printProd=
            (delg, pow, rdx, prod, msd) => {
                value-=1;
                countOnly(delg, pow, rdx, prod, msd);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", value.ToExpression(), prod);
            };

        R digitProd=
            default(R)!=(digitProd=default(R))?default(R):
            (delg, pow, rdx, prod, msd) => {
                var x=pow>0?rdx:1;

                for(var call=(pow>1?digitProd:delg); x-->0; )
                    if(msd>0)
                        call(delg, pow-1, rdx, prod*x, msd);
                    else
                        call(delg, pow-1, rdx, x, x);
            };

        Console.WriteLine("--- start --- ");

        var watch=Stopwatch.StartNew();
        digitProd(printProd, power);
        watch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("  total numbers: {0}", total);
        Console.WriteLine("          zeros: {0}", CountOfZeros(power-1));

        if(count>0)
            Console.WriteLine("      non-zeros: {0}", count);

        var seconds=(decimal)watch.ElapsedMilliseconds/1000;
        Console.WriteLine("elapsed seconds: {0}", seconds);
        Console.WriteLine("--- end --- ");
    }

    static int Pow(int x, int y) {
        return (int)Math.Pow(x, y);
    }

    static int CountOfZeros(int n, int r=10) {
        var powerSeries=n>0?1:0;

        for(var i=0; n-->0; ++i) {
            var geometricSeries=(1-Pow(r, 1+n))/(1-r);
            powerSeries+=geometricSeries*Pow(r-1, 1+i);
        }

        return powerSeries;
    }

    static String ToExpression(this int value) {
        return (""+value).Select(x => ""+x).Aggregate((x, y) => x+"*"+y);
    }
}
```

In the code, `doNothing`, `countOnly`, `printProd` are for what to do when we get the result of digit product, we can pass any of them to `digitProd` which implemented the full algorithm. For example, `digitProd(countOnly, power)` would only increase `count`, and the final result would be as same as `CountOfZeros` returns.

Comment: Note the statement `digitProd(printProd, power);` in fact is slow because of the console output. Replace it with `digitProd(doNothing, power);`, the calculation is performed without printing, and that would be the actual time of calculation.

Answer (score 2):

### Calculating a product from the previous one

Because the numbers are consecutive, in most cases you can generate one product from the previous one by inspecting only the units place.

For example:

12345 = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5 = 120

12346 = 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 6 = 144

But once you've calculated the value for 12345, you can calculate 12346 as **(120 / 5) * 6**.

Clearly this won't work if the previous product was zero. It does work when wrapping over from 9 to 10 because the new last digit is zero, but you could optimise that case anyway (see below).

If you're dealing with lots of digits, this approach adds up to quite a saving even though it involves a division.

### Dealing with zeros

As you're looping through values to generate the products, as soon as you encounter a zero you know that the product will be zero.

For example, with four-digit numbers, once you get to 1000 you know that the products up to 1111 will all be zero so there's no need to calculate these.

### The ultimate efficiency

Of course, if you're willing or able to generate and cache all the values up front then you can retrieve them in O(1). Further, as it's a one-off cost, the efficiency of the algorithm you use to generate them may be less important in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you provide some code(or pseudocode) to elaborate the cache mechanism described in the answer?

Comment: @KenKin I just mean to pre-calculate the values and then put them in an array or hash table in your code (or possibly a database if there are too many to fit in memory, although obviously that has its own inefficienies). For example, if you already had an array with the values, getting arr[12345] would be O(1).

Comment: Well .. although there would be some performance impact in practice, I think it's conceptually correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the length of your numbers and the length of the sequence if would go for some optimization.

As you can limit the maximum size of the number you could iterate over the number itself via an increasing modulus.

Let's say you have the number 42:

```
var Input = 42;
var Product = 1;
var Result = 0;

// Iteration - step 1: 
Result = Input % 10; // = 2
Input -= Result;
Product *= Result;

// Iteration - step 2:
Result = Input % 100 / 10; // = 4
Input -= Result;
Product *= Result;
```

You can pack this operation into a nice loop which is probably small enough to fit in the processors caches and iterate over the whole number. As you avoid any function calls this is probably also quite fast.

If you want to concern zeros as abort criteria the implementation for this is obviously quite easy.

As [Matthew said already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587532/how-to-calculate-the-digit-products-of-the-consecutive-numbers-efficiently/17635056#17635056): Ultimate performance and efficiency will be gained with a lookup table.

The smaller the range of your sequence numbers is, the faster the lookup table is; because it will be retrieved from the cache and not from slow memory.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create an array that represent the decimal digits of a number and then increase that number just as you would in real life (i.e. on an overflow increase the more significant digit).

From there I'd use an array of products that can be used as a tiny lookup table.

E.g.
the number 314 would result in the product array: 3, 3, 12
the number 345 would result in the product array: 3, 12, 60

Now if you increase the decimal number you'd only need to recalculate the righter most product by multiplying it with the product to the left. When a second digit is modified you'd only recalculate two products (the second from the right and the outer right product). This way you'll never calculate more than absolutely necessary and you have a very tiny lookup table.

So if you start with the number 321 and increment then:

```
digits = 3, 2, 1      products = 3, 6, 6
incrementing then changes the outer right digit and therefore only the outer right product is recalculated
digits = 3, 2, 2      products = 3, 6, 12
This goes up until the second digit is incremented:
digits = 3, 3, 0      products = 3, 9, 0 (two products recalculated)
```

Here is an example to show the idea (not very good code, but just as an example):

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Numbers2
{
    class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Maximum of supported digits. 
        /// </summary>
        const int MAXLENGTH = 20;
        /// <summary>
        /// Contains the number in a decimal format. Index 0 is the righter number. 
        /// </summary>
        private static byte[] digits = new byte[MAXLENGTH];
        /// <summary>
        /// Contains the products of the numbers. Index 0 is the righther number. The left product is equal to the digit on that position. 
        /// All products to the right (i.e. with lower index) are the product of the digit at that position multiplied by the product to the left.
        /// E.g.
        /// 234 will result in the product 2 (=first digit), 6 (=second digit * 2), 24 (=third digit * 6)
        /// </summary>
        private static long[] products = new long[MAXLENGTH];
        /// <summary>
        /// The length of the decimal number. Used for optimisation. 
        /// </summary>
        private static int currentLength = 1;
        /// <summary>
        /// The start value for the calculations. This number will be used to start generated products. 
        /// </summary>
        const long INITIALVALUE = 637926372435;
        /// <summary>
        /// The number of values to calculate. 
        /// </summary>
        const int NROFVALUES = 10000;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Started at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));

            // set value and calculate all products
            SetValue(INITIALVALUE);
            UpdateProducts(currentLength - 1);

            for (long i = INITIALVALUE + 1; i <= INITIALVALUE + NROFVALUES; i++)
            {
                int changedByte = Increase();

                Debug.Assert(changedByte >= 0);

                // update the current length (only increase because we're incrementing)
                if (changedByte >= currentLength) currentLength = changedByte + 1;

                // recalculate products that need to be updated
                UpdateProducts(changedByte);

                //Console.WriteLine(i.ToString() + " = " + products[0].ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Done at " + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the value in the digits array (pretty blunt way but just for testing)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="value"></param>
        private static void SetValue(long value)
        {
            var chars = value.ToString().ToCharArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < MAXLENGTH; i++)
            {
                int charIndex = (chars.Length - 1) - i;
                if (charIndex >= 0)
                {
                    digits[i] = Byte.Parse(chars[charIndex].ToString());
                    currentLength = i + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    digits[i] = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Recalculate the products and store in products array
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="changedByte">The index of the digit that was changed. All products up to this index will be recalculated. </param>
        private static void UpdateProducts(int changedByte)
        {
            // calculate other products by multiplying the digit with the left product
            bool previousProductWasZero = false;
            for (int i = changedByte; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (previousProductWasZero)
                {
                    products[i] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i < currentLength - 1)
                    {
                        products[i] = (int)digits[i] * products[i + 1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        products[i] = (int)digits[i];
                    }
                    if (products[i] == 0)
                    {
                        // apply 'zero optimisation'
                        previousProductWasZero = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Increases the number and returns the index of the most significant byte that changed. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private static int Increase()
        {
            digits[0]++;
            for (int i = 0; i < MAXLENGTH - 1; i++)
            {
                if (digits[i] == 10)
                {
                    digits[i] = 0;
                    digits[i + 1]++;
                }
                else
                {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            if (digits[MAXLENGTH - 1] == 10)
            {
                digits[MAXLENGTH - 1] = 0;
            }
            return MAXLENGTH - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

This way calculating the product for 1000 numbers in the billion range is nearly as fast as doing that for the numbers 1 to 1000.

By the way, I'm very curious what you're trying to use all this for?

Comment: `what you're trying to use all this for?` .. I've commented in the question.